# Is there a way to dynamically set the void state style of an Angular animation depending on input?

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

I am trying to dynamically set the [void state](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#the-void-state) style of an Angular (2) component animation.

I have a component that is rendered on "create" and re-rendered on "update". In both cases a **void => * transition** is triggered. However, for "update" I'd like a different void-style as for "create".

Example: **Create**

```
state("void", style({ opacity: 0, transform: "scale(0.8)" }))
```

Example: **Update**

```
state("void", style({ opacity: 1, transform: "scale(1)" }))
```

Can this be achieved?

Comment: I don't understand why you try to create multiple void states, instead of multiple visible states? 
Anyway, you can't assign styles to void state, as it says in the docu: 'Note that in this case the styles are applied to the void state directly in the transition definitions, and not in a separate state(void) definition.'

Comment: @MartinJavinez I can see why my question may sound challenging and sure, there could be alternative solutions but before I look into those, I'd like to know if it is possible to set a void style depending on values passed to a component via @Input?